# Simulink error : Invalid template makefile specified

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am trying to run a Simulink simulation and collect the data generated in a Matlab script.

The Simulink model run correctly and give an excepted result when it is run via Simulink.

However, when I am trying to run the Matlab script which run the Simulink model and process the data collected, an error occured in the Simulink Diagnostic Viewer :

```
Invalid template makefile specified
Component: Simulink | Category: Model error
```

Here is the code I am using in the Matlab script :

```
clear all;close all; clc;

Tps_sim = 5;

T = 0.001;
K = 25.24;
tho = 0.149;
A = 0.35;
B = -0.3;
S = 15;
Kteta = 2047/(2*pi);
Gzm=15/(15-((abs(A)+abs(B))/2));

Q1 = - 1.752;
Q0 =   1.767;
Q = Q0 - Q1;
t = transpose(0:T:Tps_sim);

l = 0;

for Consigne = [-3 3]
    
    l = l+1;
    
    C = Consigne * ones(1,length(t));

    E_95p = 0.95 * C;
    E_105p = 1.05 * C;
    
    figure (l) %Enlever cette ligne quand le commentaire au dessus est supprimé
    
    set_param('Lab_3','Solver','ode4','StopTime','Tps_sim','SimulationCommand','start'); %Enlever cette ligne et 3 en dessous quand supprimé le commantaire au dessus
    pause(1);
    set_param('Lab_3', 'SimulationCommand','stop');
    pause(2);
    yi = out.Ideal.signals.values;
    Si = stepinfo(yi,t,'SettlingTimeThreshold',0.05);
    TRi = Si.SettlingTime;
    
    subplot(3,1,1)
    plot(t,yi,t,C,t,out.CI.signals.values,t,E_95p,t,E_105p,TRi,yi(round(TRi/T)),'r*')
    title("Courbe d'évolution de la vitesse moteur idéal, Consigne = "+string(Consigne))
    xlabel("Temps (s)")
    ylabel("Vitesse (rad/s)")
    legend("Reponse","Consigne","Effort de Commande","Borne inférieure à 5%","Borne supérieure à 5%","Tr5% = "+string(TRi)+", Valeur = "+string(yi(round(TRi/T))));
    
    
    ym = out.ModeleNL.signals.values;
    Sm = stepinfo(ym,t,'SettlingTimeThreshold',0.05);
    TRm = Sm.SettlingTime;
    
    subplot(3,1,2)
    plot(t,ym,t,C,t,out.CM.signals.values,t,E_95p,t,E_105p,TRm,ym(round(TRm/T)),'r*')
    title("Courbe d'évolution de la vitesse modèle non-linéaire, Consigne = "+string(Consigne))
    xlabel("Temps (s)")
    ylabel("Vitesse (rad/s)")
    legend("Reponse","Consigne","Effort de Commande","Borne inférieure à 5%","Borne supérieure à 5%","Tr5% = "+string(TRm)+", Valeur = "+string(ym(round(TRm/T))));
end
```

Here is the Simulink model I am working with :
[image: Simulink model named "Lab_3"]

[image: Zoom on the top]
[image: Zoom on the bottom]

If you have any clue why this problem occured, it would be greatful and useful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally figured out why, I am using Quark library with a real motor usually but not here, and the System Target File Description changed from the Generic Real-Time Target (grt.tlc). You can change that in the "Hardware" Tab in Simulink.